# System.NotImplementedException C# Xamarin,Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Iam porting an android app to Xamarin.android. The project builds successfully but gives  some runtime error. As I am new to programming in C# for android I am unable to figure out how to resolve it:-
Here is my java code:-

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (msg.what == MSG_SURFACE_CREATED) {
        contentWidth = 0;
        contentHeight = 0;
        requestLayout();
        return true;
      } else {
        Log.w("Unknown msg.what: " + msg.what);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Here is what i tried in C# :-

```
private Android.OS.Handler handler = new Android.OS.Handler(new myCallback ());

        private class myCallback : Android.OS.Handler.ICallback //inner class
        {
            public myCallback()
            {
            }

            FlipViewController fp;    //Create instance of outer class 
            public myCallback(FlipViewController _fp) //pass the instance to constructor of inner class
            {
                fp = _fp;
            }
            #region ICallback implementation

            public bool HandleMessage (Message msg)
            {

                if (msg.What == MSG_SURFACE_CREATED)
                {
                    contentWidth = 0;
                    contentHeight = 0;

                    fp.RequestLayout ();

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    FlipperzLog.w("Unknown msg.what: " + msg.What);
                }
                return false;
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }

            #endregion

            #region IDisposable implementation

            public void Dispose ()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }

            #endregion

            #region IJavaObject implementation

            public IntPtr Handle 
            {
                get {
                    throw new NotImplementedException ();  //Error here
                }
            }

            #endregion



Instance    {System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at Flipperz.FlipViewController/myCallback.get_Handle () [0x00001] in c:\Users\pooja.gaonkar\Documents\Projects\Flipperz\Flipperz\com.zevenpooja.flip\FlipViewController.cs:88
at Android.Runtime.JValue..ctor (Android.Runtime.IJavaObject) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JValue.cs:79
at Android.OS.Handler..ctor (Android.OS.Handler/ICallback) [0x000c1] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-18/src/generated/Android.OS.Handler.cs:152
at Flipperz.FlipViewController..ctor (Android.Content.Context,int) [0x0000b] in c:\Users\pooja.gaonkar\Documents\Projects\Flipperz\Flipperz\com.zevenpooja.flip\FlipViewController.cs:37
at Flipperz.FlipHorizontalActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00029] in c:\Users\pooja.gaonkar\Documents\Projects\Flipperz\Flipperz\com.zevenpooja.flipperz\FlipHorizontalActivity.cs:27
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-18/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2178
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.9482ba20-59f9-4425-b64d-e6ea29c92c79 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0001f>
}   System.NotImplementedException
```

Comment: you are throwing NotImplementedException , either implement those or just comment and see

Comment: @qwr thanks for your response.. I tried commenting out the section but it gives me an error saying i need to implement it.

Comment: yes it return value,so you have to do. Actually i am not familiar with xamarin.I need to look at documentation to see what it need to be returned

Comment: on java we just inherit that object and override.isntead of implementing interface ,try just to inherit from Handler class

Comment: @qwr can you give me an example

Comment: found from docs that you have to inherit Java.Lang.Object .see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just read [xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/) here that you have to inherit  `Java.Lang.Object`
so with interface it should be:

```
private class myCallback : Java.Lang.Object ,Android.OS.Handler.ICallback //inner class
{
}
```

See if above will work

Direct inheriting(extending) from class On java will be:

```
 class myHandler extends Handler {


        public myHandler(  /*your ctor*/ ) { 
        } 

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // a message is received; 
            if (msg.obj != null) { 
                    Your_object content = (Your_object) msg.obj;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
```

Direct inheriting(extending) from class On C# will be:

```
class myHandler : Handler {


    public myHandler(  /*your ctor*/  ) { 
    }

    public override void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        // a message is received; 
        if (msg.obj != null) { 
        Your_object content = (Your_object) msg.obj;
        }
        base.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my java code as well.. can you  please have a look and update like wise

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar  see my answer and this http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/

Comment: thanks for your help it worked when i extended the class with Java.Lang.Object. Ill mark you answer as accepted.